# Angular 2 - routing for a module loaded lazy with sevral components in it

Tags: angular

I have a module which contains 2 components (UserAppsComponent and UserAppComponent) and I'd like to load the module lazy.

Root module code:

[image]

In my root router I have:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{ path: '', redirectTo: '/Dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: 'Dashboard',  component: UserDashboardComponent },
{ path: 'UserApps',  loadChildren: './user-apps-module/user-apps.module#UserAppsModule' },
{ path: 'UserApp/:appId',  loadChildren: './user-apps-module/user-apps.module#UserAppsModule' }
```

];

Lazy module code:
[image]

In my child router I have:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{ path : 'UserApps', component : UserAppsComponent },
{ path : 'UserApp/:appId', component : UserAppComponent }
```

];

Unfortunately this doesn't work for me. I can see that it loads the module JS at Chrome Network tab but there's no output, no console messages. Just empty page. How do I have it working?

Comment: could you provide your module definition ?

Comment: You can put the definition of root module and lazy loading module

Comment: I've uploaded screenshots.

Comment: where are the modules of routes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For lazy loading, you should make all the routes that go to the lazy module have the same prefix. Right now your routes are

```
UserApps
UserApp/:appId
```

Change to something such as:

```
userapps
userapps/:id
```

Now that both routes start with the same thing, in your main router, you need only one path that leads to the lazy loaded module:

```
const routes:Routes = [    
   { path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
   { path: 'dashboard',  component: UserDashboardComponent },
   {   // path to lazy module
       path:         'userapps', 
       loadChildren: './user-apps-module/user-apps.module#UserAppsModule'
   }
]
```

Next, UserAppsModule needs its own module root component that will hold the `<router-outlet>` for that module's path (lazy module paths are not rended in `AppComponent` RouterOutlet, but in a child outlet that belongs to the lazy module. Suppose your UserAppsModule root component is `UserAppsRootComponent`; the routes of the `UserAppsModule` would be

```
const routes:Route = [
    {
        path:'',
        //should contain <router-outlet> for this module's routes
        component: UserAppsRootComponent, 
        children: [
            //full path: /userapps
            {path: '', component: CrisisListComponent},
            //full path: /useapps/:id
            {path: ':id', component: CrisisListComponent},
        ]
    }
];
```

By the way i recommend using only lower case chars in your routes

Comment: "UserAppsRootComponent" and <router-outlet> - I got your idea! Let me give it a try...

Comment: I've added UserAppsRootComponent and <router-oulet> tag into its template but still have an empty page. It loads a child module but the child router does not loads child components if I have 'userapps' in the child router:

    `const routes: Routes = [
    { path : 'userapps', component : UserAppsRootComponent,
        children : [
            { path : '', component : UserAppsComponent },
            { path : ':id', component : UserAppComponent }
        ]
    }
];`

Comment: `But...if I have just '' it loads the child components wiht UserApps:
const routes: Routes = [
    { path : '', component : UserAppsRootComponent,
        children : [
            { path : '', component : UserAppsComponent },
            { path : ':id', component : UserAppComponent }
        ]
    }
];`

Looks like the router can't see 'path : 'userapps''.

Comment: @AlexLavrik You're right there was a mistake in my response. I've edited the last code block. The path of the root component of `UserAppsModule` should be the empty string `''`, not `'userapps'`

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks so much! )))